# How to extract graph region from a picture using Image Processing

Tags: image-processing, ocr

Given an scanned image containing graphs and text , how can I extract only images from that picture . Can you mention any image processing algorithms .

Answer (score 0):

You could do connected component analysis, filtering out everything that does not look like character bounding boxes. An example paper is *Robust Text Detection from Binarized Document Images*
(https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220929376_Robust_Text_Detection_from_Binarized_Document_Images), but there are a lot of approaches. It depends on your exact needs if you get away with something simple.

There is a lot more complex stuff available, too. One example: *Fast and robust text detection in images and video frames* (http://ucassdl.cn/publication/ivc.pdf).